# Installing sopcast in Ubuntu

Tags: ppa, sopcast

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'd like to install sopcast. I don't want to install it in wine, but I have found a ppa ferramroberto/sopcast. Is there a way to find out whether it's safe to add this ppa? I don't know how to be sure whether to trust it or not. I guess it's safe, but maybe someone can confirm it! Thanks!

Comment: Why not via wine? I installed via wine in Kubuntu 16.10 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

he is a long term member (2009) and trust-able in my opinion. : https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto

Member since:
    2009-08-31

- Debian GNU/Linux Users
- Kubuntu Users
- Launchpad Users
- Ubuntu Advertising
- Ubuntu Screencast Team
- Ubuntu Studio
- Ubuntu Venetian    Translators
- Ubuntu-Tour Team